# How to edit Apache configuration so that the changes of git pull don't reflect right away?

Tags: linux, git, apache, shell

I'd like to edit the Apache configuration on Linux so that the changes of every git pull don't reflect right away.

I'd like it to only stage after Apache is restarted.

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: Wtf is "changes of every gitpull don't reflect right away"?

Comment: @peterh i'm trying to make the changes on the repository reflect automatically on a specified time only not right after pulling on git

Comment: Explain this in the question *clearly* and I will change my downvote to up.

Comment: Btw, read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), it is important for you. Others won't talk to you, only vote your question down (or to close), and they are right.

Comment: @peterh Why don't you tell me what's wrong with my question? I don't get it, others understood it they even answered my question

Comment: I tell. Did you read the link in my previous comment? (And yes, maybe *somebody* will even answer it, but most of the people seeing your questions like this click away on the spot.) Now you had luck, you got an answer, and even from one of the highest reputed site users, but it is an exception. There are clear signatures of the high-level content, and what the site asks from you is the minimum of the minimums. Probably you've learned these rules in the elementary school, why you don't follow them?

Comment: @peterh easy tiger. I'm just asking you the specifics of your comments and you just kept on answering me with this generic things. And yes I have read the link you've given but it's all about grammatical guidelines and I can't understand if you're pertaining to the technical side or grammatical side of the question. You don't have to be rude. You giving me a link about those who's not good with English is rude enough already.

Comment: Ok, partially you are right. But anyways, first there are these grammatical "details". Maybe you can say, that your question is without them also understable, but it is not true. It is *much* harder to decipher if there isn't a clear sentence in your text. And, what is more important: few will take you seriously, if you are writing on the level of a [functional illiterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_illiteracy). (Which would be a sorrowful situation and would deserve extra help from us, but in most cases its reason is only lazyness and not a real mental problem.)

Comment: Second, as you formulate your question (and, generally: if you are formulating *anything*), you should imagine the viewpoint of the readers. They are out of your head, they don't know what you know. You *shouldn't* refer in your question anything, which is known only for you. Now check the [first](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37853008/1), un-edited, un-aided version of your question. What is the relation of your apache to your git? What is *""changes of every gitpull don't reflect right away"*? You are serving git repos from an apache, or what? Nobody knows this, it needs to be regularly

Comment: *deciphered*. VonC did it for you, but only because you had luck. Most of the questions like yours are closed fast here, and after some such tries, if you aren't developing, the site won't accept more questions from your account. And it does it perfectly okay, on my opinion it is much more friendly to you as you would deserve. *You* are requesting help from others, *your* task would be to make their answer as easy as it is possible. Not *our* task would be to decipher, what could have you thought as you wrote your text, while you were even lazy to form a single sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't change the Apache configuration, but rather what Apache manages.

It can show the content of a git repo, but that should not be the one where the changes are done.

You can have two repos:

- one for the changes
- one for reflecting the changes when Apache restart (ie, a git pull from the first)

That is:

```
git clone first/repo path/to/second/repo
# make Apache serve path/to/second/repo
```

When restarting Apache, add before the apachectl start:

```
cd path/to/second/repo
git pull
```

Comment: Is there a way to just disable the auto-staging of changes from git in Apache? Changes will just reflect if i restarted Apache

Comment: @AlvinV. I am not aware of an "auto-staging" changes from git in Apache. Apache is just there to serve files. My answer suggests to serve files that change only when Apache restart. The fact those files are from a git repo can then be safely ignored by Apache.

Comment: How can apply these having a repository containing changes and another one that reflects when Apache restarts

Comment: @AlvinV. you simply add the first repo as a remote to the second one (the second one being served by Apache): see my edited answer.

Comment: ok thank you i'am actually a beginner here :) so you're saying that it isn;t necessary to change anything from /etc/apache2/ ???